# Difference beween += and s1+s2 in case of java strings

Tags: java, string, concatenation

I need to write longer queries which are generated dynamically and get appended in a string variable.As we all know,following code will make different instances of string variable each time we do +=.

```
String str = "";

  str +="select * from";
  str+=" users where userid = 1";
```

I want know whether following will do the same or will just make a single instance?

```
String str = "select * from "+" users where userid = 1";
```

Answer (score 3):

If it's only literals the compiler might optimize that but if not each `+` operation on strings will create an intermediate instance. In fact `a += b` is just a short way of writing `a = a + b`, to the compiler it is the same.

Btw, I have a strong feeling that you want to concatenate values into the query. If you can *please avoid that* since it might introduce severe security issues (SQL injection). Use `PreparedStatement` instead.

Comment: Thanks.But my second code is not a=a+b but its a = b+c that I wanted to know

Comment: @KevinEsche in the context of the question it should be clear that strings are meant, but I added "on strings" for clarification anyways. Thx for the hint.

Answer (score 2):

Both instances create multiple strings.

If you need to *build* your query string, just use a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

```
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder()
query.append("select * from ");
query.append(" users where userid = 1");
```

For completeness' sake, please look into [`Prepared Statements`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) if you are constructing SQL Queries yourself.

Answer (score 2):

From a semantic perspective `s += s1;` and `s = s + s1;` are identical.

JLS 15.26.2. says:

> "A compound assignment expression of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent to E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2)), where T is the type of E1, except that E1 is evaluated only once. "

In this case:

```
   s += s1;
```

becomes

```
   s = (String) ((s) + (s1));
```

which is becomes

```
   s = s + s1;
```

when you remove the redundant typecast and parentheses.

---

However your examples (rather than the question title) are about String >>literals<<.  For String literals, we have to consider the constant expression rule.  A constant expression will be evaluated at compile time if it meets certain criteria set down in JLS 15.28.  In your examples:

```
    "select * from " + " users where userid = 1";
```

is a constant expression, but any expression that involves a simple or compound  assignment operator is NOT a constant expression.

In fact, JLS 15.18.1 says this (about the String `+` operator):

> "The String object is newly created (§12.5) unless the expression is a constant expression (§15.28)."

Therefore, there is a difference in the number of objects created at runtime each time the statements are executed for your specific examples. The first version will create two new strings each time it is executed, and the second one will create zero new strings.

(The JLS allows no wiggle room here for the JIT compiler to optimize away the concatenation in the `+=` version, and no wiggle room for the bytecode compiler NOT to optimize the `+` away in the other version.)

Comment: Its not the question at all

Comment: I would also add that `s = s + s1;` essentially becomes `s = new StringBuilder(s).append(s1).toString();`

Comment: @Cinnam - that is an implementation detail.  The compiler is >>permitted<< to do that, but not >>required<< to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to back up and use prepared statements when building queries or you may be susceptible to SQL injection attacks.

Having said that, using StringBuilder is the way to go, but also try and use reused string constants at the top so you do not constantly create them eg. in loops.